# Don't let me add in a listbox more items than shown in the combobox

Tags: c#

[image]
I have a combobox with the items 
1
2
3
...
40
,if I chose the value 4 then I should be able to add in my listbox no more than 4 values.This is what i was thinking of but isn't working.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int allowedItemsCount = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedText, out allowedItemsCount);
        int currentItemsCount = listBox1.Items.Count;

        if (currentItemsCount < allowedItemsCount)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text); 
        }
    }

    private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            while (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
            }
        }

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedText, out x);
        int count = listBox1.Items.Count;
        if (count > x)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            int difference = count - x;
            for (int i = 0; i < difference; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.Items.Count - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the full code you asked for but is not working...now the add button is not working.

Comment: And if you select n the listbox have more than n items, should it delete the extra items? Also, from how many places do you add items to the listbox?

Comment: yes that is correct @Aimnox

Comment: From where do you add items to the listbox?

Comment: from a simple add button @PawanNogariya

Comment: try change 'Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedText, out allowedItemsCount);' to 'Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), out allowedItemsCount);'

Comment: It worked ,thank a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedText, out x);
    int count = listBox1.Items.Count;
    if (count > x)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        int difference = count - x;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < difference ; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.Items.Count-1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

As per your comment, write this code in your add button click event

```
int allowedItemsCount = 0;
Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedText, out allowedItemsCount);
int currentItemsCount = listBox1.Items.Count;

if(currentItemsCount <  allowedItemsCount)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text); // I assume your textbox id is TextBox1
}
```

Comment: with your answer nothing happens,only if i add the items in the listbox and after i select an option from the combobox no matter what option it will just clear my listbox,I want to select for example value 3 in combobox and it shouldnt let me add more than 3 items in the listbox.

Comment: I updated the code. You should write the updated code in your add button click event. I do not know the text box id from where you are adding items to the list so I put `TextBox1` there, you can replace it with the original id. Actually you should put your full code in your question. Like added button click event code, your texbox, button ids etc.

Answer (score 0):

For removing extra items:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.TrimExcess(Int32.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedText));
    //If you control the items on the combo so you know for sure the parse will work, ignore the tryparse
}
```

And for adding items to the ListBox (and control it does not have to much items:

```
private int addToListBox(object item)
{
    if(listbox1.items.count>=Int32.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedText)) return -1;
    listbox1.items.add(item);
    return 0;
 }
```

And when you need to add to that listbox use `addToListBox`and not `listbox1.items.add`

Answer (score 0):

This will check if you can add line to listbox1 and if its changed number of line it will delete it.
Adding is made by button.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int x = 0;
                Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), out x);
                int count = listBox1.Items.Count;
                while(count > x){
                    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(count - 1);
                    count = listBox1.Items.Count;
                }
            }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), out x);
        if (listBox1.Items.Count < x)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(x); //add whatever you want
        }
    }
```

Comment: React to your edit:for adding items used listBox1.items.Add(textBox.Text)